# How to pack gtk_entries and gtk_combobox to gtk_list_store

Tags: listview, combobox, gtk

Just as title states - I need to create a gtk_list_store with 3 columns:
Editable gtk_entry | Combobox | Editable gtk_entry

As far as I know I can't just pack GtkWidget into list.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use a TreeView, you should probably start by reading the [Tree and List Widget Overview](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/TreeWidget.html). In short, a ListStore is just a data model. The tree view looks at the data model and uses its columns and cell renderers to display a certain view of that data. The only widget in the whole setup is the GtkTreeView. How you can display your data depends on the cell renderers you use: the ones shipped with GTK+ are fairly limited (definitely nothing like a combo box) but you can implement your own.

That said, using a TreeView is significantly more complex than using other widgets and apart from some edge cases (like huge amounts of data) the benefits aren't that great. Often using a [GtkListBox](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkListBox.html) is easier and produces better results -- especially if you want your widgets to be editable. On older Gtk+ versions (pre-3.10) the ListBox is not available but you should be able to get most of the benefits by using a GtkGrid.

Comment: Yeah, I have some experience with gtk_trees but it was only with PIXBUF and TYPE_STRING columns so it was rather easy to handle.
I would love to use GtkListBox but I have to use stable release which for now is still 3.6.4 - for now I have just used horizontal box to which I'm packing other widgets and it's all in scrolled windows - kind od noobish way around but I still prefer that than handling with tree_view for now.

Thanks anyway, I hope they release new stable version soon.